# Lighttpd fails to start after reboot

Tags: systemd, raspbian, lighttpd

I installed lightpd on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Stretch) in this way:

```
apt-get install -y lighttpd php-common php-cgi php
lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
usermod -aG www-data pi
```

after starting the service I checked and it worked fine, serving the php web pages as expected. After rebooting the service doesn't start anymore:

```
$ systemctl status lighttpd.service
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-09-09 21:26:39 CEST; 6min ago
  Process: 1302 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 1295 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1302 (code=exited, status=255)

Sep 09 21:26:38 rpi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 09 21:26:39 rpi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here the configuration file:

```
$ cat /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf 
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
)

server.document-root        = "/home/pi/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that if any directory it's going to use is not mounted to a tmpfs system. Lighttpd is not able to recreate them after installing.

The solution is then to manually create on every reboot the following directories:

- `/var/log/litghtpd`
- `/var/run/lighttpd`

owning them as `www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable selinux by typing `setenforce 0` and then restart lightpd to check if it works. If it does then edit `nano /etc/selinux/config` and change the value of SELINUX from `enforcing` to `disabled` in order to permanently disable selinux. Very often on Linux os' SELINUX is preventing web servers from starting.

Answer (score 0):

To check configuration: `lighttpd -t -f lighttpd.conf`

To start in foreground with logging on stdout: `sudo lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf`

More info: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/TutorialConfiguration